# Insert into sorted linked list

Tags: java

I'm attempting to implement a sorted linked list with insertion, deletion, and check if integer exists methods and I'm currently having trouble understanding why my insertion method isn't working quite right. It inserts integers into the linked list but they are sorted backwards, I've tried moving around the conditionals but it doesn't work the way it should.

```
void insert(int x){
    LinkedList newLink = new LinkedList(x);
    if (front == null) {
        front = newLink;
    } else if (x > front.x){
        newLink.next = front;
        front = newLink;
    } else {
        LinkedList current = front.next;
        LinkedList before = front;
        while (current != null){
            if (x < front.x) {
                before = current;
                current = current.next; 
            }
            newLink.next = before.next;
            before.next = newLink;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Well, if `x` is greater than your current head, then you are *prepending* it to your list.  That's what makes the list sorted in descending order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will fix your problems, plus, I added some comments for you to understand my changes in your code :

```
void insert(int x) {
    LinkedList newLink = new LinkedList(x);
    if (front == null) {
        front = newLink;
        // insert in head if x is lower than the head
    } else if (x <= front.x) {
        newLink.next = front;
        front = newLink;
    } else {
        // find the first node which value is lower than x (or the tail)
        LinkedList current;
        for (current = front; current.next != null && x >= current.next.x ; current = current.next);
        // to remove duplicates
        if (x != current.x) {
            newLink.next = current.next;
            current.next = newLink;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the conditional in the for loop is preventing me from adding more than 2 integer values, I tried inserting a '1' & '3' and that worked but trying to insert '2' it failed. It is in ascending order now though which helped a ton.

Comment: How did it fail ? Exception ? Wrong output ?

Comment: I didn't get an exception and it didn't output anything, this is what my console looked like http://imgur.com/AhwM1Oq I'm using toString(); to output the linked list

Comment: Could you provide the whole code on PasteBin or CollabEdit ?

Comment: The code of `Console` does not compile but I will wite my own test class. I will let you know if I find what's wrong

Comment: It was working for me a second ago, edited with the toString(); method I'm using to output the list here http://pastebin.com/NFVAkTdH

Comment: I fixed it, the for condition was indeed wrong since I looked at the value of the wrong node

Comment: I've tried implementing your fix and for some reason when I try to add the 3rd integer it replaces the previous one and still won't let me insert more after, I'm trying to figure it out through the debugger with no luck

Comment: Thanks, it worked with that test class you wrote. I'm assuming there's something wrong with mine in the way it handles the users inputted integer, still having trouble with it.

Comment: If you want, I could take a look to that too (maybe in a separate question)

Comment: I figured out that there was a missing set of empty curly braces after the for loop, it compiled and worked perfectly after. Now if I wanted to write a method to delete an integer would you be able to guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Alright thanks, I got it working myself. Also for your code implementation, how can I change the conditional to make sure it doesn't add duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (x > front.x){
    newLink.next = front;
    front = newLink;
}
```

If the new link is *greater* than the front, make the new node the `front` node, and set its next node to the last front. You are inserting at the front of the list in reverse sorted order.

```
if (x < front.x) {
    before = current;
    current = current.next; 
}
```

You are always comparing to the `front` node as well, not your `current` node.

Answer (score 0):

Please find attached my implementation. Please use and modify to your needs.

Attention! This implementation will drop equal values!

```
/******************************************************************
 * Adds the given string to the sorted list. If the string already
 * is in the list, then the list will not be modified.
 * 
 * @param list The sorted list of strings
 * @param str The string to be inserted if not there already
 * @return Returns true if the list has changed otherwise false
 */
public static boolean
add2SortedList( List<String> list, String str ) {
    int res = 0;

    //--- Loop through list from end to front
    for ( int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0 ; i-- ) {

        //--- Compare to current entry
        res = str.compareTo( list.get( i ));

        //--- Already in list => return
        if ( res == 0 )
            return false;

        //--- Bigger than current one => insert after
        if ( res > 0 ) {
            list.add( i + 1, str );
            return true;
        }
    }

    //--- Insert at head of list
    list.add( 0, str );
    return true;
}


/******************************************************************
 * Adds the given value to the sorted list if its not already there.
 * 
 * @param list the sorted list of values
 * @param value the value to be inserted if not there already
 * @return returns true when value was added, else false
 */
public static boolean
add2SortedSet( List<Integer> list, Integer value )
{
    int size = list.size();
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )
    {
        int res = value.compareTo ( list.get( i ));

        //----- Insert before this element
        if ( res < 0 ) {
            list.add( i, value );
            return true ;
        }

        //----- New element already in list
        if ( res == 0 )
            return false ;
    }

    //----- Append to end of list
    list.add ( value );
    return true ;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The default way to insert in a linkedList:

```
LinkedList<Integer> myList = new LinkedList<>();

myList.add(238);
myList.add(7);
..        
Collections.sort(myList);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

for a different way to sort use the interface Comparable

Comment: Does not answer the question at all since we are talking about a custom implementation of the linked-list data structure